# How to Secure a jax-rs web service with TomEE?

Tags: java, ssl, https, jax-rs, apache-tomee

I have a TomEE server and I enabled ssl on it (with https on port 443), using this [guide](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html) to create a Certificate Keystore, So I'm using Netbeans 8.2 IDE, I created a Maven Web Apllication, next step I created a Restful Web Service from DataBase (I already have a mysql database table), and I deployed the rest web service and it's working fine, So now I want to make this web service secure so when my android client wants to use this webservice they must be logged in first, can someone please help me with this? I already read about Spring web services but I prefer JavaEE 8 and jax-rs, (because it seems more simple to me)

So should I add something in the maven `pom.xml` (the project also doesn't have a `web.xml` because I just need the webservices nothing more), or should i use Apache Shiro ?

Comment: After some research I decided to use Spring Boot framework which made everything easy for me with it's embedded Tomcat server and for security of Rest API now I use JWT authentication.